# How to remove this border?

Tags: html, html-lists, border

Here is an image of my problem:

[image]

My code:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Accommodation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services & Amenities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the error displayed in your example image.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following css:

```css
.nav li {
  border-style: none;
}
```

You can try it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=none).

Comment: @na.rubel You should accept it as answer if it will solved your problem. By clicking on right symbol.